# Configuring Jetty JSP support in embedded mode in Maven project

Tags: jsp, jetty, embedded-jetty

I can visit .html pages with Jetty, but when I visit a .jsp page I get:

> 0 13:21:13 / [INFO] No JSP support. 
>   Check that JSP jars are in lib/jsp and
>   that the JSP option has been specified
>   to start.jar

I added the following as dependencies:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
  <artifactId>jetty-webapp</artifactId>
  <version>8.0.0.M1</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp</groupId>
  <artifactId>jsp-api</artifactId>
  <version>2.1</version>
</dependency>
```

Does that fulfill the "check that JSP jars are in lib/jsp" part of the error message?

Also, I have no idea what "check that the JSP option has been specified to start.jar" means in this context.  I have the following:

```
  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    Server server = new Server();

    SelectChannelConnector connector = new SelectChannelConnector();
    connector.setPort(8080);
    server.addConnector(connector);

    WebAppContext webApp = new WebAppContext();
    webApp.setContextPath("/");
    webApp.setWar("src/main/webapp");
    server.setHandler(webApp);
    server.start();
    server.join();
  }
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I got it to work by adding the Mortbay JSP dependency (this is in Gradle notation, but you get the idea):

```
compile 'org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-io:8.0.0.M3'
compile 'org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-server:8.0.0.M3'
compile 'org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-servlet:8.0.0.M3'
compile 'org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-util:8.0.0.M3'
compile 'org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-webapp:8.0.0.M3'
compile 'org.mortbay.jetty:jsp-2.1-glassfish:2.1.v20100127'
```

There's a [larger writeup available on my blog](http://www.benmccann.com/blog/embedded-jetty/).

Comment: Jetty 8 supports the jsp 2.2. In the jetty hightide 8.0.0 distro they include the following in the jsp dir:

`com.sun.el_2.2.0.v201105051105.jar`
`javax.el_2.2.0.v201105051105.jar`
`javax.servlet.jsp.jstl_1.2.0.v201004190952.jar` `javax.servlet.jsp_2.2.0.v201103241009.jar` `org.apache.jasper.glassfish_2.2.2.v201108011116.jar` `org.apache.taglibs.standard.glassfish_1.2.0.v201004190952.jar`

I'm assuming this will give you jsp 2.2 support. The downside is this a lot of jars to keep track of. I wonder when jetty will have a jetty-jsp.jar? It would sure be nice!

Comment: Actually, the jetty distribution has these dependencies as well.  They can be found at the following url:

[http://download.eclipse.org/jetty/orbit]

The jetty distribution's pom downloads the jars at that url and packs them in the distribution's lib directory.

Comment: Wow, I tried all solutions below which caused a lot of missing classes: ExpressionFactory and more. This was the only one that simply worked

Answer (score 10):

I know this has been answered a while ago. I could not get the answer from Ben McCann to work for me. However, i had luck by adding JSP support directly to Jetty by adding

```
    <!--jsp support for jetty, add the 2 following -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.mortbay.jetty</groupId>
        <artifactId>jsp-2.1</artifactId>
        <version>6.1.14</version>
        <type>jar</type>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.mortbay.jetty</groupId>
        <artifactId>jsp-api-2.1</artifactId>
        <version>6.1.14</version>
        <type>jar</type>
    </dependency>
```

Strangely, this was not supported by the version 6.1.24 I originally had.

So in total, that made my pom.xml look like this:

> http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
>       4.0.0
>
> ```
> <groupId>wikiproject</groupId>
> <artifactId>wikiproject</artifactId>
> <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
>
> <properties>
>     <jetty.version>6.1.14</jetty.version>
> </properties>
>
>
> <!-- Jetty dependencies -->
> <dependencies>
>     <dependency>
>         <groupId>org.mortbay.jetty</groupId>
>         <artifactId>jetty</artifactId>
>         <version>${jetty.version}</version>
>         <type>jar</type>
>     </dependency>
>
>     <dependency>
>         <groupId>org.mortbay.jetty</groupId>
>         <artifactId>jetty-util</artifactId>
>         <version>${jetty.version}</version>
>         <type>jar</type>
>     </dependency>
>
>     <dependency>
>         <groupId>org.mortbay.jetty</groupId>
>         <artifactId>jetty-plus</artifactId>
>         <version>${jetty.version}</version>
>         <type>jar</type>
>     </dependency>
>
>     <!--jsp support for jetty, add the 2 following -->
>     <dependency>
>         <groupId>org.mortbay.jetty</groupId>
>         <artifactId>jsp-2.1</artifactId>
>         <version>${jetty.version}</version>
>         <type>jar</type>
>     </dependency>
>     <dependency>
>         <groupId>org.mortbay.jetty</groupId>
>         <artifactId>jsp-api-2.1</artifactId>
>         <version>${jetty.version}</version>
>         <type>jar</type>
>     </dependency>
>
>     <dependency>
>         <groupId>org.apache.ant</groupId>
>         <artifactId>ant-antlr</artifactId>
>         <version>1.7.1</version>
>     </dependency>
>
> </dependencies>
> ```

and my start class (which i added in folder `\src\test\java\com\company\wikiproject` )

> ```
> package com.company.wikiproject;
> import org.mortbay.jetty.Connector;
> import org.mortbay.jetty.Server;
> import org.mortbay.jetty.bio.SocketConnector;
> import org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext;
> /**  
>  * User: Jesper Rønn-Jensen  
>  * start wiki pages  
>  */
> ```
>
> public class Start {
>
> ```
> public static void main(String[] args) {
>     Server jettyServer = null;
>     try {
>         jettyServer = new Server();
>
>         SocketConnector conn = new SocketConnector();
>         conn.setPort(8080);
>         jettyServer.setConnectors(new Connector[]{conn});
>
>         WebAppContext context = new WebAppContext();
>         context.setContextPath("/");
>         context.setWar("src/main/webapp");
>
>         jettyServer.setHandler(context);
>         jettyServer.start();
>     } catch (Exception ignore) {
>         if (jettyServer != null) {
>             try {
>                 jettyServer.stop();
>             } catch (Exception e1) {
>                 e1.printStackTrace();
>             }
>         }
>     }
> }
> ```
>
> }

Comment: This only works for Jetty 6 and older. That's pretty old since Jetty 8 is almost out now. I updated my answer to provide a better solution, so take another look.

Comment: This is still a valuable answer, since e.g. Solr ships with jetty 6.
You can just add `org.mortbay.jetty:jsp-2.1:6.1.14` to your POM and combine it with any jetty 6 version. The Maven central doesn't have version 6.1.26 of jsp-2.1.

Answer (score 10):

I have done it without using the jars from the Jetty distribution, using only Maven dependencies:

```
<properties>
    <jetty.version>8.1.0.RC0</jetty.version>
    <glassfish.javax.version>2.2.3</glassfish.javax.version>
    <glassfish.javax-impl.version>2.2</glassfish.javax-impl.version>
    <glassfish.jstl.version>1.2</glassfish.jstl.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <!-- Jetty Webapp-->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
        <artifactId>jetty-webapp</artifactId>
        <version>${jetty.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- JSP Support -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.web</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.servlet.jsp</artifactId>
        <version>${glassfish.javax.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.web</groupId>
        <artifactId>jsp-impl</artifactId>
        <version>${glassfish.javax-impl.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- EL Support -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.web</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.el</artifactId>
        <version>${glassfish.javax.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.web</groupId>
        <artifactId>el-impl</artifactId>
        <version>${glassfish.javax-impl.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- JSTL Support -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
        <version>${glassfish.jstl.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.web</groupId>
        <artifactId>jstl-impl</artifactId>
        <version>${glassfish.jstl.version}</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Answer (score 6):

Building upon Simon Huet's excellent answer, here's my take:

```
<properties>
    <bundle.name>nsb-${project.version}</bundle.name>
    <glassfish.javax.version>2.2.3</glassfish.javax.version>
    <glassfish.javax-jstl.version>1.2.1</glassfish.javax-jstl.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>

    <!-- Jetty Webapp -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
        <artifactId>jetty-webapp</artifactId>
        <version>${jetty.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- JSP Support -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.web</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.servlet.jsp</artifactId>
        <version>${glassfish.javax.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- EL Support -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.web</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.el</artifactId>
        <version>${glassfish.javax.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- JSTL Support -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.web</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.servlet.jsp.jstl</artifactId>
        <version>${glassfish.javax-jstl.version}</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <artifactId>jstl-api</artifactId>
                <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp.jstl</groupId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>
```

Answer (score 1):

After reading this stackoverflow page (nice job) as well as http://wiki.eclipse.org/Jetty/Howto/Configure_JSP, I finally got this to work as well.  Since my config is slightly different, I thought I'd contribute back.  I have an embedded Jetty 8 installation without the 'javac' compiler, and I got it to work by using the eclipse compiler and setting the system property before creating the server, like this:

```
System.setProperty("org.apache.jasper.compiler.disablejsr199", "true");
Server server = new Server();
```

And using the following maven configuration:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.apache.geronimo.specs</groupId>
  <artifactId>geronimo-servlet_3.0_spec</artifactId>
  <version>1.0</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty.orbit</groupId>
  <artifactId>javax.el</artifactId>
  <version>2.2.0.v201108011116</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty.orbit</groupId>
  <artifactId>javax.servlet.jsp</artifactId>
  <version>2.2.0.v201112011158</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty.orbit</groupId>
  <artifactId>javax.servlet.jsp.jstl</artifactId>
  <version>1.2.0.v201105211821</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty.orbit</groupId>
  <artifactId>org.apache.jasper.glassfish</artifactId>
  <version>2.2.2.v201112011158</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty.orbit</groupId>
  <artifactId>org.apache.taglibs.standard.glassfish</artifactId>
  <version>1.2.0.v201112081803</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty.orbit</groupId>
  <artifactId>org.eclipse.jdt.core</artifactId>
  <version>3.7.1</version>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 1):

Jetty 9.1.3, http://www.eclipse.org/jetty/documentation/current/configuring-jsp.html, and just adding jetty-jsp worked for me (plus the web.xml config from the url). No need to add jars from outside the jetty groupId (ie. mortbay).