# jsp support in embedded jetty with out maven

Tags: jsp, maven, struts2, jetty

I want to run a struts 2 application in an embedded jetty server. 
but I can not config embedded jetty with jsp support. there are many articles describing how to config jsp support with maven. but i have no knowledge in maven. is there any solution to provide jsp support for embedded jetty with out knowledge of maven ?

Answer (score 0):

Check this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4235082/configuring-jetty-jsp-support-in-embedded-mode-in-maven-project). If you don't want to use Jetty 8, check the second answer.

The only thing that you have to understand about Maven or Gradle is that they take care of adding the correct libraries into your class path. So that means that if you add the correct libraries into your class path then the jetty server will run with JSP support.

But I think that is better if you spend some time learning Maven or Gradle (or both) because it will make your java programming life easier.

Answer (score 0):

It is a complex thing and cannot be explained in a few
words.

I have written a [tutorial](http://zetcode.com/java/jetty/embedded/) about how to enable JSP
support in embedded Jetty. Maven is not used. 
It contains a simple JSP page, an Ant build file, and 
the Java POJO. See the *Enabling JavaServer Pages* header.