# JSP war file in embedded jetty

Tags: java, jsp, jetty

I have a war file which is created from eclipse Dynamic web project, it has jsp and servlet files. It's working fine by run on server in eclipse with tom cat server. Now I exported it to war file and trying to deploy in Embedded jetty server, I'm using Jetty 9.1.0. Its throwing

```
No JSP support.  Check that JSP jars are in lib/jsp and that the JSP option has been specified to start.jar
```

What I'm missing, I cant find a fix. I'm using jetty-distribution-9.1.0.v20131115's all jar files.

Comment: I think http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4235082/configuring-jetty-jsp-support-in-embedded-mode-in-maven-project can help you

Comment: @jsjunkie that answer is woefully out of date and incorrect for Jetty 9.1.0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found the answer, we need to add few jar files to make the embedded jetty to accept JSP/Servlet support.

```
ecj-4.2.2
jetty-jsp-2.1-7.5.4.v20111024
jsp-2.1-glassfish-2.1.v20091210
jsp-api-2.1-glassfish-9.1.02.B04.p0
```

And you must include web.xml in the war file. Then extract the war file setWar as the extracted war file directory. Then Bingooooo....

Comment: Use the `org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-jsp:${jetty-version}` maven meta-module for the correct list of dependencies for your chosen version of Jetty.

Comment: Or grab everything out of the `${jetty-distribution}/lib/jsp` directory.

Comment: All of the jars in `lib/jsp/*.jar` make up what is required for jsp support - https://gist.github.com/joakime/7961563#file-jetty-distribution-9-1-0-v20131115-log-L106-L112